# javascript: own function is not defined in map

Tags: javascript

I get the following error `ReferenceError: double is not defined`

Code:

```
Number.prototype.double = function (){
    return this*2;
}
x=[1,2]
console.log(x.map(double));
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: You should *really* not extend or modify native javascript prototypes (it can create all kinds of unexpected side effects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that like that. The reason is that `this` inside of `map` is not a number. That's why you cannot do it with a `prototype` like you wish.

What you can do is the following: get the passed parameter from `map`

```
Number.double = function (e){
    return e*2;
}
x=[1,2]
console.log(x.map(Number.double));
```

**EDIT**: if you really need the prototype solution, you can do the following:

```
Number.prototype.double = function (e){
    if (e) return e*2;
    else return this*2;
}
x=[1,2]
console.log(x.map(Number.prototype.double));
```

Comment: But `double()` is now no longer a method of `Number` - this has changed the code completely.  You can no longer say `n.double()` to double a number.

Comment: @RichieHindle I don't think it changed the code, but I've added the solution for your case too. I actually think if it was used only for this specific case then there was no need to put it inside of the prototype; the first method just adds a `static` method instead of `member` one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your method on an instance of Number:

```
...
console.log(x.map(function (n) { return n.double(); }));
```

Answer (score 0):

*double* is a property of Number prototype, not a global variable.

```
x.map(function(y){return y.double()});
```